# how to set php cookie with a expiration time & if cookie exists how to redirect user to another page

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want when the user come to my page the `index.php`. It should create a cookie with an expiration time and if the user again tries to visit that page in 5 minutes he should be redirected to a page showing USER TIMEOUT.

`index.php` should create a cookie

If in 5 minutes the user again visits that page he/she should get a `USER TIMEOUT` message.

Answer (score 5):

Use this on login or on the method when you are creating the cookies

```
setcookie("user", "User Name", time()+5*60);
```

The syntax for setcookie() method is-

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

where **`expire`** is the time when the cookie will expire, you can give this time in relative to the current time by adding few more second to the value returned by `time()` method, **`name`** is the name of cookie, by which the value will be accessed, and the **`value`** is the value. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

And on other page check with-

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
   header("Location:timeout.php");
```

The methods setcookie() and header() should be called before the output is sent. The alternative(a little tricky) of header() you can do with -

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          document.location = "timeout.php";
      </script>';
```

This will redirect the page using javascript.

**Content of index.php-**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['visited']))
{
   $_SESSION['visited'] = time();
   setcookie("user", "User Name", time()+5*60);
}
else
{
   if(!isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
      header("Location:timeout.php");
}
?>
<html><body>This is my page</body></html>
```

**Content of timeout.php-**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['visited']);
?>
<html><body>Timeout, again go to <a href="index.php">main page</a></body></html>
```

Comment: Yes time() will return current time and after 5*60 seconds+current time the cookies will expire

Comment: Make sure header() is at the very top of your PHP page and you are not outputting any HTML before it.

Comment: @user2294087 Yes what @allejo said, `header()` or `setcookie()` should be called before any HTML output is send.

Comment: @user2294087 than wait for 5 min let the cookie will expire, again reload the page. Or give the expire time less

Comment: I think you are creating and checking the cookie on the same page `index.php`?

Comment: @user2294087 that's correct, problem is in creating the cookie...check the code where you are giving the expire time while creating the cookies it's taking more time or u have given the same try with `time()+(1*60)` and the cookie will expire after 1 minutes

Comment: Can't it redirect automatically after the time is ended ??

Comment: Yes using javascript u can do that, with the help of `setTimeout()` method and `document.location` like - `setTimeout(function(){document.location="timeout.php"},5000);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", $expire);

//cookie for 5 mins
$time = time()+60*5;
setcookie("page_auth", "Alex Porter", $time);
}
else
{
if(isset($_COOKIE["page_auth"]))
{
    header('location:timeout.php');
    setcookie("user", "", time()-3600);
}
}
```